# How to Create Custom List in SharePoint 2010 Programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i have tried the following way,

http://devendra-sharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/01/creating-list-programatically-in_30.html

But i am not able to create list.

Becuase i am getting the following error.

'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb' does not contain a definition for 'EnsureList' and no extension method 'EnsureList' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please advice.

Thanks,
Aasai

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
private SPList CreateList(string LName)
  {
    if (spWeb.Lists.TryGetList(LName) == null)
      {
        spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        spWeb.Lists.Add(LName,"This is Programatically created list", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
      }
    return spWeb.Lists[LName];
  }
```

Thanks